# Is there an idiomatic expression to refer to an “ambush” journalist?

Tags: expressions, phrase-usage

***[Ambush journalism](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journalism_genres)*** is an expression from the early ‘80s that refers to:

> aggressive tactics practiced by journalists to suddenly confront and question people who otherwise do not wish to speak to a journalist, in places such as homes, vacation spots, hallways, and parking lots.

[Steve Weinberg](https://journalism.missouri.edu/staff/steve-weinberg/), an investigative reporter of the Missouri School of Journalism describes "ambush interview" as:

> a loaded shorthand term describing the practice of reporters "*catching source unaware, usually in a public place, then acting rudely.*”

(Wikipedia)

I am looking for the expression commonly used to refer to a journalist who practices ambush journalism. “*Ambush journalist*” doesn’t  appear to be used. I’ve found some usage instances of [*aggressive journalist*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ambush%20journalist%2C%20aggressive%20journalist%20&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Caggressive%20journalist%3B%2Cc0) but it is a too a generic definition.

So, what are the expressions  (also slang ones) used to describe such journalists?

Comment: @KannE are those BrE or AmE expressions?

Comment: These are _paparrazi_ tactics... although [_paparrazi/papparazo_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/paparazzo) itself refers to tabloid photographers, who are only journalists in the very loosest sense of the word. Also related: the verb [to doorstep](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/doorstep).

Comment: _Ambush journalist_ does seem to be in use. A quick googling finds me examples [here](https://money.cnn.com/2016/10/05/media/jesse-watters-chinese/), [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vB5vL4bJeug), [here](https://www.conservapedia.com/Chris_Wallace) and [here](https://www.thewrap.com/hillary-clinton-christopher-stevens-video-jason-mattera/). It also follows naturally from _ambush journalism_, of course. What makes you think _ambush journalist_ can't be used?

Comment: @tmgr - ambush journalism is an expression that is a actually used, maybe in is not common. Ambush journalist is not, I can’t find any evidence. Whatever the case, what expression would you use to refer to the kind of journalist described above?

Comment: I think most people I know would use *paparazzo* for those kinds of people.

Comment: @Cerberus - paparazzi do a different job, “*The ***paparazzi are photographers*** who follow famous people around, hoping to take interesting or shocking photographs of them that they can sell to a newspaper.*” (Collins)

Comment: @user240918 Perhaps I wasn't clear, sorry. I think that _ambush journalist_  actually _is_ in use. (I found quite a few examples - see my previous comment.) If you want to avoid it, you might also consider the word [_tabloid_](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tabloid), which in North America (but definitely not in the UK) has moved beyond a page size and newspaper descriptor to mean _lurid and sensational_ as in _tabloid TV shows_... so you just _might_ get some mileage out of that, although it is far from hitting the nail on the head.

Comment: Approaching this from another angle (although maybe not a helpful one) - an ambush interview could be one of many techniques used by a reporter into order to get the story, but does not necessarily mean they should be characterized as an "Ambush Journalist".   Are they an aggressive investigative reporter?  Perhaps this can make the term less generic.   That said - +1 for @tmgr for doorstep/doorstepping/doorstepper, though the definition doesn't necessarily imply aggression.

Comment: @Balaz2ta - I think that the techniques described in my question are clear and that this kind of journalism is more and more common in the harsh completion among  TVs, papers etc. so I find it surprising that there in no established expression for this.

Comment: What is wrong in calling the journalist: **[aggressive](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-206752/Gilligan-aggressive-reporter.html)**, **invasive**, or even a [**pushy reporter**](https://www.google.com/search?num=20&ei=3nAjXLroPOW7jwS4trKQDw&q=%22pushy+reporter%22&oq=%22pushy+reporter%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...3675.7690..8177...0.0..0.113.204.1j1......0....1..gws-wiz.-9ApjVz2LH4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The contemporary meaning of 'predatory journalist' perhaps comes closest to the contemporary meaning of 'ambush journalist'. Another, possibly better candidate is 'stalkarazzo' (in plural, 'stalkarazzi', modeled on 'paparazzi' and 'paparazzo').

In the [*Newspapers+ Publishers Extra*](https://www.newspapers.com/) corpus (paywalled), the uses (including repetitions and false positives; plurals of 'reporter' and 'journalist' are also included in count totals) of various terms break down thus:

```
Ambush reporter/journalist:       104, 1917-2006 / 36, 1981-2014
Aggressive reporter/journalist:  5374, 1884-2018 / 1127, 1870-2018
Predatory reporter/journalist:     54, 1904-2014 / 71, 1907-2009
Stalkarazzi:                      368, 1994-2014
```

To be sure, in use each of the terms has unique nuances and a unique range of meaning. 'Ambush journalist', for example, is not so broad a term as 'aggressive journalist' and, historically at least, 'predatory journalist' was also used to label journalists who stole their material.

The meaning of 'stalkarazzi' shades more toward a label for journalists who use modern surveillance and other technologies (long-range photography, shotgun microphones, camera phones) than does 'ambush journalists', although both terms include the full range of the other: 'ambush journalists' describes the tactics and strategies of 'stalkarazzi' and vice versa.

A contemporary example of the use of 'stalkarazzi' from [*The Los Angeles Times* (Los Angeles, California), 18 May 2014](https://www.newspapers.com/image/203706513/?terms=%22stalkarazzi%22):

> THE MARTINEZ. The last of the string of plush hotels that line the Croisette and another popular spot for the celebrities and the people who stalk them...it was here last year that the notorious Psy impersonator was spotted...waving to the *stalkarazzi*...the camera-phone crowds waiting outside the barriers snapped pictures of him and believed he was the real...deal.

An example using both 'stalkarazzi' and 'predatory journalists' from [*The Los Angeles Times*, 16 Mar 1998](https://www.newspapers.com/image/159939264/?terms=%22predatory%2Bjournalist%22). As implied, 'predatory journalists' is the broader category that, like 'aggressive journalists', includes both 'stalkarazzi' and 'ambush journalists':

> Unfortunately, the problems associated with the stalkarazzi are not limited to California; these predatory journalists often cross state lines to gain pictures and recordings.

In both contemporary and historical use, 'aggressive reporter' covers a much broader range of meaning than 'ambush reporter', and is more frequently used with a neutral or positive connotation. This example comes from [*The Morning Call* (Allentown, Pennsylvania), 15 Nov 2018](https://www.newspapers.com/image/506614152/?terms=%22aggressive%2Breporter%22):

> "The White House has made very clear that they don't like the content of the reporting by CNN and Jim  Acosta," Boutrous said. "Rudeness really is a code word for 'I don't like you being an aggressive reporter.'"

Answer (score 5):

I have found *ambush reporter* more commonly than *ambush journalist* in my searches. For instance, "ambush reporter" appeared a few times in *[Dilbert](https://dilbert.com/search_results?terms=ambush%20reporter)*, as Dogbert was an "ambush journalist" who acts like "Mike Wallace." These examples are from the early 1990s, and reflect the term's wide application to everyone from *60 Minutes*'s Mike Wallace to the reporters who would approach sports stars or CEOs on the street.

Extended articles on the subject like [this one](https://www.prnewsonline.com/how-to-counter-the-ambush-reporter/) or [this one](https://www.pahomepage.com/news/hampshire-college-calls-cops-on-fox-news-reporter/614441295) don't vary much from "ambush reporter" or "reporter." You might also be able to use variants like *ambush interviewer*. This suggests to me that there isn't a precise idiom available to describe this person beyond applying the "ambush" or similar label to *reporter*, *journalist*, or *interviewer*.

Answer (score 1):

**[Gotcha journalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gotcha_journalism)** seems relevant to the question, from wiki

> a pejorative term used by media critics to describe interviewing methods that appear designed to entrap interviewees...

.

Comment: That's not quite the same: it refers to the practice of leading the interviewee toward making statements which are damaging in some respect. In this case, the interviewee is *willingly* participating in the interview, even though the interview takes a path they would not willingly take. In "ambush journalism" the interviewee is forced into an interview without prior agreement.

Answer (score -2):

I would say:
MEDDLESOME 
or 
INTRUSIVE:

MEDDLESOME

stresses an annoying and usually prying interference in others' affairs.

// a meddlesome 
landlord

INTRUSIVE

implies a tactless or otherwise objectionable thrusting into others' affairs.

//**Intrusive 
reporters 
disturbed 
their 
privacy.**

(From Merriam-Webster)

Comment: Thanks, but these are generic terms that can be applied to a different context. What I am looking for is a;idiomatic expression used for journalists who practice ambush journalism.